# how to open Azure SQL SERVER in office network, I am able to open AZure SQL Using my Home network in SSMS but cant open in Office network

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

I am not able to open Azure SQl Server in my Office network using SSMS

I can open Azure SQl SERVER using my home network from SSMS.

Please help me how can I configure Azure SQL SERVER in office network and work using SSMS.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with connecting to Azure SQL Server from the Office Network and got any error? If yes, please provide the error details!

Comment: Have you looked in the 'Firewalls and virtual networks' tab of the Azure Sql server in the portal to see where you are allowed to connect from?

Comment: Hi  I am am getting error like "Microsoft Sql Server, Error : 10060  .   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) "Microsoft Sql Server, Error : 10060

Answer (score 0):

The error usually means the TCP port is not properly set or is being blocked by the firewall.

> To access the Azure SQL database from your local, ensure that the [firewall on your network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql#connections-from-the-internet) and local computer allows outgoing communication on TCP port 1433.

There are some troubleshooting steps provided in detail in this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection#error-messages) for the same error message.